# Adding components to jList Java

Tags: java, swing, bufferedreader, jlist

I stored user details in a txt file, separating names and passwords and other details using ",". Now I am trying to output all the usernames to a jList.

```
try {
            File f = new File("/Users/Nisham/Desktop/javapwd.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);


            while(sc.hasNextLine()){

                String line = sc.nextLine();
                String[] details = line.split(",");
                String name = details[0];

               jList2.add(name);

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It seems like I can't add string to the list. Is there any possible way to do so.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: it says, not suitable method found for add(String)

Comment: May it's just me been a grumpy old developer, but I'd discourage the use of the `add/removeElement` methods in favor of a good `ListModel`, it's generally more efficient as well. See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

Comment: "*it says, not suitable method found for add(String)"* - Then you should have consulted the [JavaDocs for `JList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) and the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) first before posting

Comment: @MadProgrammer, `May it's just me been a grumpy old developer, but I'd discourage the use of the add/removeElement methods in favor of a good ListModel,` - yes well you need to learn to walk before you run. You need to learn how to use the LIstModel first and then learn what the drawbacks are before you can improve on the default implementation. For most people the default implementation is fine since it is not a mission critical system, just people learning to code.

Comment: @camickr I never learnt anything other then to use the model ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I assume you mean to create and use your own custom implementation of a ListModel. I know for myself I am self taught (as you can probably tell from many of my answers) and learned how to use Swing (and Java in general) from the Swing tutorial and from reading answered questions found in forums. It was overwhelming for me trying to learn all new concepts every time I tried to do something new. Knowing that there were default implementations of the models and views of Swing components allowed me to learn at my pace rather than trying to be a master designer from the beginning.

Comment: @camickr I was thinking just the `DefaultListModel`, since the "model" is such a core concept to Swing, if you can learn to understand it, it makes it easier to learn the other aspects of the API - that's just me and everybody's different. Ps - I like your answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps think about using DefaultListModel.

I'd have a good read of the [following](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html).

Specifically the `addElement` and `removeElement`.

Comment: addElement() and removeElement() are methods of the DefaultListModel.